# Stream Audio/Video from an iphone app using HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying existing to stream music/video on an iphone using HTTP Live Streaming. I read the apple docs on HTTP live streaming (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and I get how it works.

What it doesn't say is how one would use iphone as a server? Do I have to add the tools to my ios app(mediastreamsegmenter, variantplaylistcreator) and run it as a NSTask or is there some kind of native support to stream media files.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stream from an iPhone app you can't do this with the iPhone acting as a server. You need a separate server where you can send data from the iPhone app. So you can use the camera or the microphone in the app to get live content and then you can send asynchronously data to the server, which using mediastreamsegmenter and variantplaylistcreator will convert the data to ts segments and then will append them at the end of the m3u8 file and meanwhile another iPhone app can act as a client and watch the live content that you are streaming from the first app.

From my experience this is the only way to achieve that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of using it as a streaming server, I am instead sending over the data packets to the peer client and it starts streaming it as it receives it.